# 1-2 Oblivious Transfer - Can the recepient obtain both secrets by manipulating v?

Tags: rsa, oblivious-transfer

Refer to the chart on 1-2 oblivious transfer : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer

I'm Bob, I know *N*,*e*,*x0*,*x1*. Can I send Alice a v value that, by knowing the *m'0*,*m'1* received, I can crack both *m0* and *m1*?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

> Can I send Alice a v value that, by knowing the m'0,m'1 received, I can crack both m0 and m1?

One would hope not; if Bob can, this would show that the proposed protocol does not meet the security requirements of an OT protocol.

However, in this case, selecting such a $v$ value would appear to be difficult.  What Bob would need to do is find two values $y, y'$  that map to two values with an Alice specified difference, that is, $y^e - y'^e = x_1 - x_0$.

If Bob can do that, we can learn both values (by setting $v = y^e + x_0$.  Conversely, if he knows a value $v$ for which he can learn both secrets, he can compute such a $y, y'$ pair, hence this reformulation of the problem is tight.

However, the mapping $x \rightarrow x^e$ acts unpredictably (if you don't know the factorization); there is no known way to find such a pair for a random difference $x_1 - x_0$.